# 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'data' in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've defined a url in `urls.py` to export some data as `csv` using `Django 3.0.6` and `djangorestframework 3.10.3`

```
    re_path(
        r'^(?:v1/)?export/csv/$',
        api.ExportAPIView.as_view(),
        name='export'
    ),
```

And here is the `api.py` code to handle this url:

```
class ExportAPIView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        http_response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        http_response[
            'Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'

        writer = csv.writer(http_response)
        writer.writerow(['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
        writer.writerow(
            ['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"])

        return http_response
```

The response of this code should be simple `csv` file containing two rows but I'm getting this error instead:

```
AttributeError at /v1/export/csv/
'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Note that I've used `renderer_classes = [CSVRenderer]` from `djangorestframework-csv` and `StreamingHttpResponse` with no luck either. So what is the problem that I'm missing here?

Comment: If you think more details is required from the code to find out what I'm missing, comment and I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `renderer_classes = [CSVRenderer]` is set, you should be able to use something like this:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    content = [
        ['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'],
        ['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"]],
    ]
    response = Response(content)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'

    return response
```